# Trying to add a database table to my JTable in Netbeans

Tags: java, api, netbeans, jtable

As the title question states, I am attempting per the instructions of this tutorial: https://blogs.oracle.com/NetBeansSupport/entry/populating_jtable_from_mysql_database

And the message I keep receiving is: "Tables without primary keys are not supported by the Java Presence API"

The thing that is driving me crazy is that the table that I created myself using SQL does have  a primary key...

Are there other(working) methods to do this, because I have looked and tried and have failed time after time again...

btw this is the SQL for those who are wondering(the server is running via localhost)

1. CREATE TABLE Customers
2. (
3. KL_NR INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
4. NAAM VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
5. EMAIL VARCHAR(30),
6. ADRES VARCHAR(30),
7. PLAATS VARCHAR(100),
8. POSTCODE VARCHAR(6),
9. TELEFOON VARCHAR(13),
10. BEDRIJFSNAAM VARCHAR(30),
11. PRIMARY KEY (KL_NR)
12. );

Just FYI I have a form setup in my application that can add rows in the database, so it's not a connection issue.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: changed it to only 1 PK but as i stated in the  comments it doesn't change anything. even when i try to import it using:  the table contents and binding it.

Comment: Not sure what NetBeans is doing here behind the curtains, but i guess your PK should be only on the KL_NR column. Composite primary keys are usually considered an anti pattern these days.

Comment: What version of NetBeans do you use? It works with 7.3 but it doesn't show first 2 columns (obviously because you have 3 PK's).

Comment: Did u coded or using Netbeans interface drag/drop for doing this task?

Comment: @gyro even when just having the KL_NR as primary key the same problem persists

Comment: @che drag and drop, I tried other coding methods but those failed me, trying to find a solution for this issue first before asking a more complecated question

Comment: @brano88 I have 7.3.1

Comment: I suggest you to code and post an `SSCCE` such that we can help you quickly and it also helps you to learn much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by making an updateTable class

```
      String sql = "select * from customers";
      preparedStatement=connect.prepareStatement(sql);
      resultSet=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
      Table_customer.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(resultSet));
//this part forces the premade pallet Jtable to morph 
//into the model of my mysql server database table
```